# How can I get data from firebase in android and set it to my model?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was creating an app and connect it to firebase and I have successfully uploaded the data by firebase documentation, and now I can't get it, I couldn't find any documentation about it.
Can you please show me the code of how to get my data AND set it to my model like for example:

```
Model.setTitle(firebase.collection.get("Title"));
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your database and then use a ValueEventListener :)

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);

        HERE GET THE VARIABLE AND SET TO YOUR TITLE :) 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

In some cases you may want a callback to be called once and then immediately removed, such as when initializing a UI element that you don't expect to change. You can use the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method to simplify this scenario: it triggers once and then does not trigger again.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Please post answer after understanding the problem

Comment: He's trying to get data from firebase no? @Ashish

Comment: Sorry for being rude but he didn't even posted his database structure

Comment: Don't need to see his structure to advise what to do next :) was just advice what to do next not exactly how to do it i guess my bad :) @Ashish